# AWS IoT SDK - main L#206 Error subscribing : -28 (C code)

Tags: aws-sdk, iot, policy, aws-iot, policies

I am trying to run the example in [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-embedded-c-sdk.html) from AWS IoT (AWS IoT Embedded C SDK).

My `aws_iot_config.h` file has the following configuration:

```
#define AWS_IOT_MQTT_HOST              "XXXXXXX.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com" ///< Customer specific MQTT HOST. The same will be used for Thing Shadow
#define AWS_IOT_MQTT_PORT              8883 ///< default port for MQTT/S
#define AWS_IOT_MQTT_CLIENT_ID         "c-sdk-client-id" ///< MQTT client ID should be unique for every device
#define AWS_IOT_MY_THING_NAME          "SM1" ///< Thing Name of the Shadow this device is associated with
#define AWS_IOT_ROOT_CA_FILENAME       "iotRootCA.pem" ///< Root CA file name
#define AWS_IOT_CERTIFICATE_FILENAME   "deviceCert.crt" ///< device signed certificate file name
#define AWS_IOT_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME   "deviceCert.key" ///< Device private key filename
```

This is how my policies are:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:338639570104:topic/sm1"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:338639570104:topic/sm1"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run the `subscribe_publish_sample` example, I am getting the following error:

> DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#236  ok
>       [ Protocol is TLSv1.2 ]
>       [ Ciphersuite is TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384 ]
>
> DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#238     [ Record expansion is 29 ]
>
> DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#243   . Verifying peer X.509 certificate...
>   DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#252  ok
>
> DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#262   . Peer certificate information    ...
>
> DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#264       cert. version     : 3
>         serial number     : 3C:75:FE:30:01:DD:A3:B9:EF:72:DC:F6:7A:5C:A2:54
>         issuer name       : C=US, O=Symantec Corporation, OU=Symantec Trust Network, CN=Symantec Class 3 ECC 256 bit SSL CA - G2
>         subject name      : C=US, ST=Washington, L=Seattle, O=Amazon.com, Inc., CN=*.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
>         issued  on        : 2017-10-12 00:00:00
>         expires on        : 2018-10-13 23:59:59
>         signed using      : ECDSA with SHA256
>         EC key size       : 256 bits
>         basic constraints : CA=false
>         subject alt name  : iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com, *.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
>         key usage         : Digital Signature
>         ext key usage     : TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
>
> Subscribing...
>   ERROR: main L#206 Error subscribing : -28

Can anyone show me what is happening? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I did not find out a good and complete tutorial related to process of sending data from a device to AWS IoT, including all the steps needed, I tried changing the policy I was using to:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "iot:*",
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

Though this wildcard on `Resource` apparently is not so good, it was the way I used, since the other policies were not working.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS IoT core policy actions are at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-policy-actions.html

The sample client needs all four MQTT policies and needs `iot:Publish`, `iot:Receive`, and `iot:Subscribe` on the sdkTest topic. The topic name is hardcoded to sdkTest in the sample. So this works:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:338639570104:client/c-sdk-client-id"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:338639570104:client/c-sdk-client-id"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:338639570104:client/c-sdk-client-id"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:338639570104:client/c-sdk-client-id"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:338639570104:*sdkTest*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:338639570104:*sdkTest*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:338639570104:*sdkTest*"
    }
  ]
}
```