# AWS IoT - No success with publish on topic attempt

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, iot, paho, aws-iot

I am testing the connection and publishing to a thing created in the AWS IoT console. I am using the following code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import ssl, random
from time import sleep

mqtt_url = "XXXXXX.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
root_ca = './certs/iotRootCA.pem'
public_crt = './certs/deviceCert.crt'
private_key = './certs/deviceCert.key'

connflag = False

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, response_code):
    global connflag
    connflag = True
    print("Connected with status: {0}".format(response_code))

def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    client.disconnect()

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print "---ON MESSAGE"
    print(msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Loaded MQTT configuration information."
    print "Endpoint URL: " + mqtt_url
    print "Root Cert: " + root_ca
    print "Device Cert: " + public_crt
    print "Private Key: " + private_key

    client = mqtt.Client("aws_connector")
    client.tls_set(root_ca,
                   certfile = public_crt,
                   keyfile = private_key,
                   cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                   tls_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2,
                   ciphers = None)

    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message

    print "Connecting to AWS IoT Broker..."
    client.connect(mqtt_url, port = 8883)
    client.loop_start()

    while 1==1:
        sleep(0.5)
        if connflag == True:
            print "Publishing..."
            ap_measurement = random.uniform(25.0, 150.0)
            client.publish("ActivePower", ap_measurement, qos=1)
        else:
            print("Waiting for connection...")
```

My policies are described as below:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:338639570104:topic/sm1"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:338639570104:topic/sm1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Apparently, the connection is working and I am getting the following output:

> Loaded MQTT configuration information.
>   Endpoint URL: XXXXXX.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
>   Root Cert: ./certs/iotRootCA.pem   Device Cert: ./certs/deviceCert.crt   > Private Key: ./certs/deviceCert.key
>   Connecting to AWS IoT Broker...
>   Connected with status: 0
>   Publishing...
>   Publishing...
>   Publishing...
>   Publishing...
>   Connected with status: 0
>   Publishing...

The problem is I am getting no messages from the publishing process. Am I doing something wrong? Is there something missing?

Comment: Have you tried using aws mqtt client library? It is slightly different from the paho implementation. https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python

Comment: No. I tried the `aws iot device sdk embedded c` which has a [problem in the subscribe operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280665/aws-iot-sdk-main-l206-error-subscribing-28-c-code). Furthermore, I saw that this python sdk also uses `paho-mqtt`. So, it works as a wrapper.

Comment: `while 1==1:` -> `while True:`? However, it seems `1==1` is `0.003 usecs` faster on my machine. Interesting. Not worth the readability cost, however, imho.

Comment: @Drise , `while 1==1` == `while True` == `while 1` == `while 1>0` == ... This part of code I just got of another example I found out at github... the problem is not related to that, so, I left as it was (though I also prefer `True`). Good observation, btw, related to performance!

Comment: @Dalton By habit, if I see `while True` I instantly assocciate that with some application or thread loop (or a giant red flag). `while 1==1` to me is not instantly recognizable as this, though my brain is quite lazy when reading code, so it might just be me.

Comment: Agree with you, @Drise .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that the AWS IoT policy associated with your IoT certificate allows publishing on the `ActivePower` topic.

Currently your policy only allows you to publish to topic `sm1`. Update it to

```
 {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "iot:Publish",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:338639570104:topic/ActivePower"
 }
```

or as a quick and dirty way of troubleshooting if this is a policy issue add

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "iot:*",
    "Resource": "*"
}
```

A policy this liberal is not recommended for production.

Also your subscribe policy has the wrong resource, and you need to add a policy statement for `iot:Receive` to be able to receive messages, if you were to subscribe to that topic.

[AWS IoT policy resource documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/action-resources.html)

Comment: I updated my question with the policies I have described and activated. Is there something missing?

Comment: I tried both approaches: same problem. Now I tried to delete my policy to create another one, but I am facing this problem: `The action failed because the resource conflicts with the precondition of the action. The policy cannot be deleted as versions other than than default version exist (name=SMPolicy)`.

Comment: I created a new policy, leaving the problematic one there. I just attached the new policy, that is: `{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Connect",
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Subscribe",
        "iot:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-2:338639570104:topic/*"
    }`. But, still, there is no message received from the publishing process. Apparently, the `on_message` is not working...

Comment: You are not subscribing to any topics in the code sample provided. on_message should fire when a message comes in on a topic you have subscribed to. Also note that to subscribe you need to allow iot:Subscribe on a topicfilter resource e.g. `arn:aws:iot:us-east-2: 338639570104:topicfilter/*`

Comment: Thanks by explanation. I was thinking the `on_message` was used by any feedback from the `server`. So, our publish operations do not have answers from server, right? How do we know if the operations were succeeded? Yet, how can I see the values sent to specific topics?

Comment: The simplest way I've found it to use the AWS IoT console. Select Test from the left side bar. Subscribe to `#` after it connects. You should see any published messages. You can also subscribe to a specific topic.